# Quarto - dynamically create sections not printing tab_models

Tags: quarto, sjplot

I am using for loop to create linear mixed model. I have 2 problems:

- headers not showing in toc, though I have depth set to 4
- `sjPlot::tab_model` not showing the summary

I have tried many different online solutions and nothing worked.

This is my code:

````
```{r}
#| error: TRUE
#| results: 'asis'


x<-c("body_mass_kg",
           "bmi",
           "obseg_nadlahti_relax",
           "obseg_nadlahti_flex",
           "obseg_goleni",
           "obseg_stegna",
           "kg_triceps",
           "kg_biceps",
           "kg_subscapular",
           "kg_suprailiac",
           "kg_front_thigh",
           "kg_medial_calf",
           "kg_abdominal")
                          


for (element in x) {

cat('#### ',element, '\n\n')

dfSelect<-dfMixedModel %>% 
dplyr::select(id, adiponectin_plasma_mg_ml, time_point, variable, value) %>% 
dplyr::filter(variable==element) %>% 
mutate(value=as.numeric(value),
       time_point=time_point+2)




if (shapiro.test(dfSelect$value)$p.value>=0.05) {
  
  print("Navaden linear-mixed model")

model <- lmer(value ~ adiponectin_plasma_mg_ml + time_point + (1|id), data = dfSelect)

} else {

  print("Robusten linear-mixed model")
  
model <- rlmer(value ~ adiponectin_plasma_mg_ml + time_point + (1|id), data = dfSelect) 

}


tab_model(model)
  
  
# cat("\n:::\n")
}
```
````